# What is 'safe' way to rig to allow for future editing of bone positions?

Tags: rigging, rigify

I'm trying to figure out the best way to rig a model so that I have the  flexibility to make tweaks to the rigged mesh and the rig itself in the future.

I have a character mesh that I created, rigged (using Rigify and then baking a rig from that) and then animated.  Then I decided to make changes to the original mesh.  I shortened the neck and moved the shoulders forward a bit.  This caused all my facial and arm bones to go out of alignment.  I then selected the armature and switched into edit mode and dragged the bones into the new positions the best I could, but the result was a distorted mess.  Even rebinding the mesh to the skeleton with automatic weights did not help.

As much as I like the rig that Rigify generates, it seems to be pretty inflexible to these kind of edits.  Is there a better approach?  Should I be building my rigs from scratch?

Comment: Maybe keep the original metarig and adjust that to your model, and use it to regenerate the rig. You could look at [blenrig](https://cloud.blender.org/p/blenrig), I haven't used it yet but it uses mesh deform that might be more flexible to underlying mesh changes. Blenrig and the pdf docs are free while the video tutorials are members only.